# Getting error for Karma Tests

Tags: karma-jasmine

I am getting the below error on my karma unit test:

npm WARN karma-coffee-preprocessor@0.1.3 requires a peer of karma@>=0.9 but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-junit-reporter@1.2.0 requires a peer of karma@>=0.9 but none was installed.
npm WARN karma@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN karma@1.0.0 No repository field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalled karma and installed it again

```
$ npm uninstall -g karma
$ npm install karma --save-dev
```

This worked for me.
I got an error while trying to install it again, saying refusing to install dependency of itself. Change "name" in package.json from "karma" to "karma-test" and it worked. :)